# Error while creating ldap custome attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, apacheds

I am trying to create cutom field and object
                           `DN: uid=55e44a75e4b0f16711714165,ou=people,dc=myDB,dc=com`

I created ldif file

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: (2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.1
        NAME 'adminStatus'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15)
attributeTypes: (2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.2
        NAME 'userStatus'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024})
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: (2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.3
    NAME 'statusPerson'
    DESC 'statusPerson'
    SUP inetOrgPerson
    STRUCTURAL
    MAY  (adminStatus $ userStatus))
```

When I tried to add file like

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=myDB,dc=com -W -f Desktop/statusPerson.ldif
```

it gives error

```
ldapadd: wrong attributeType at line 6, entry "cn=schema"
```

Answer (score 0):

LDIF specification states that you need a separator when you change the modification type/attribute.

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: (2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.1
        NAME 'adminStatus'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15)
attributeTypes: (2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.2
        NAME 'userStatus'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024})
-
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: (2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.3
    NAME 'statusPerson'
    DESC 'statusPerson'
    SUP inetOrgPerson
    STRUCTURAL
    MAY  (adminStatus $ userStatus))
```

Comment: I already tried  it gives error modifying entry "cn=schema"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
 additional info: attributeTypes: value #0 invalid per syntax

Comment: `$ ldapmodify -h localhost -p 2389 -D cn=directory\ manager -w secret12 -f ../status.ldif
modifying entry "cn=schema"
`

I use OpenDJ 3.x directory server.